# Experience with concurrent Subversion repository access modules

Tags: svn

We're looking at moving our repository access from svnserve to apache/Subversion Edge to enable easier administration, transport level encryption and windows authentication.

I've read several times that, assuming the processes are run as the same users, or at least with the same permissions, Subversion supports concurrent repository access with different modules (ra_svn, ra_serf, etc.).

My question: has anyone had real-life experience with this in a production environment? If so, did you experience *any* issues? Our Subversion server has ~60 users, including issue tracker and build server, so we have a bit of traffic and rely on svn running smoothly (as per usual).

Please note that I'm interested in hearing from developers as well as admins, otherwise I would've asked on serverfault, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those wishing to try, our company successfully migrated svnserve to Subversion Edge. The two Subversion servers, running as different services on the same box, were used concurrently for just over a week and we didn't hit any issues.

Whilst I still don't know whether this is officially supported, our experience was good :)

Comment: I think it is supported: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.multimethod.html

Answer (score 0):

I deployed and used SVN with Apache and used windows authentication as described in the manual of SVN and it was working great except for one issue that when committing large number of files it fails with Authentication failed error. Developers had to commit their changes in batches of 20 to 30 files. When first committing a large project I (the admin) used to do it from the server machine to be able to use file:// instead of https:// to access the repository as the problem only happens when accessing via HTTP.

I have searched for solutions for this problem and did not find a solution if any one knows about that it would be very helpful to tell us.

I do not know about ra_svn & ra_serf.

Comment: Thanks, I will test out Apache (via Edge) with lots of files (we sometimes have 1,000's per commit so any problem will show up:). What I really want to know is issues running different Subversion servers concurrently.

Comment: Why do you need to run multiple servers ?

Comment: Because we want to migrate from svnserve to Apache (using svn edge). Shifting all of our users and servers at once (relocate working copies) is no mean feat (distributed development team, release process relies on svn) and if there is a problem, we want a quick, easy way to go back. Having concurrent servers solves these issues.

Comment: I did not try deploying multiple servers before. I used one server to access all repositories and it goes without saying that if you deployed each server on a different machine everything will go fine as normal and I think deploying multiple servers on the same machine with different port for each server will be fine as well but perhaps someone who actually tried it would be more useful.